# Master of Pyromancies not unlocking on PS4

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm playing Dark Souls 3 on PS4. I spent hours to run for the Master of Pyromancies achievement, and well, I got the 27 spells.

**The thing is: nothing happens. I don't get the achievement for some reason.**

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 28 Pyromancies in Dark Souls 3, at least according to the list on [the wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Pyromancies). One of those is a DLC item though.

Comment: Mmm, I checked this wiki 50 times where it says there are 27 pyromancies on the top of it, so I just counted 27. Thank you, I realized I miss Toxic mist.